# What is the technical term for the "consecutive, discrete zoom-in shots" and what is its origin?

Tags: tropes

Let me illustrate what I mean with a GIF:

[image: Naoi believes wings for the president is fitting]

Usually, the scenes between the three or four consecutive shots don't differ much except the zoom-ins (or whatever shots are used).

A variation of this technique was [termed](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/462jjd/anime_direction_and_overdirection_panning_shots/d027y09/) the "threepeat tilt up" by a redditor, but is that the correct technical term for this kind of shots? Would the above GIF be called a "fourpeat zoom in"?

Also, was this technique borrowed from the film industry, or was it invented in anime?

Comment: I wonder if it's done for dramatic or comedic effect.  I can't think of any anime-unique scenarios in which this is done, but it does have similarities to the zoom effects we've seen in film.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are consecutive [axial cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_cut).

> Axial cuts are used rarely in contemporary cinema, but were fairly
>   common in the cinema of the 1910s and 1920s.